# PlayStore APK Error

Tags: android, apk

My app is currently Version 2(1.1) I am trying to upload an APK Version 3(1.2).

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="icykum.JasonSafaiyeh.cocg"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.2">
```

Upon upload I still get the message: You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1.

SOLUTION:
build.gradle did not update versionCode, had to do it manually.

Comment: Check your exported APK again, maybe you uploaded an old file. Your manifest stats that its versionCode is 3 already. Or maybe, are you mistaking your Manifest file?

Comment: I doubled checked, I am uploading the right APK, and yes my manifest is versionCode 3

Comment: How about trying to change it to 4 or 10, if versionCode is not a matter for you?

Comment: Okay, I tired 4. Still got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: build.gradle did not update versionCode, had to do it manually.